# Mongodb-PHP: find query with '$and' function is not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

i am working on mongodb & php & want to retrive data based on multiple conditions.

I want to retrive forms whose form_status is both Active & Draft only

My query is:

```
$formData = $formInfo->find(array('team_id' => $_GET['id'], '$and' =>array('form_status' => 'Active','form_status' => 'Draft')));
```

It is not working. What could be the right syntax in PHP??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) operator takes a "real array" of documents as it's argument. In PHP you wrap the array to produce that kind of syntax:

```php
$formData = $formInfo->find(
    array(
        'team_id' => $_GET['id'], 
        '$and' => array(
            array( 'form_status' => 'Active' ),
            array( 'form_status' => 'Draft' )
        )
    )
);
```

Note that this really woudn't make any sense unless "form_status" is actually and array itself. In which case the [**`$all`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator is a much cleaner approach:

```php
$formData = $formInfo->find(
    array(
        'team_id' => $_GET['id'], 
        'form_status' => array( 
            '$all' => array( 'Active', 'Draft' )
        )
    )
);
```

And again if this field was not an array then you really meant [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) but that can also be more clearly written for the same field with [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/):

```php
$formData = $formInfo->find(
    array(
        'team_id' => $_GET['id'], 
        'form_status' => array( 
            '$in' => array( 'Active', 'Draft' )
        )
    )
);
```

So `$all` is to `$and` what `$in` is to `$or`, but just allows you to use the same field without specifying the full document form

Comment: $formData = $formInfo->find(array('team_id' => $_GET['id'],'$and' => array(array( 'form_status' => 'Active' ),array( 'form_status' => 'Draft' ))));
foreach($formData as $data){
    var_dump($data);
}
die;

Comment: @Shaggie I think you have your terms incorrect. I was actually just editing that to explain that point. See the additions.'

Comment: ok. when i was commenting at that time recent edit was not there

Comment: thanks your last post for query with $in works perfect...thanks a lot